# Varnish page reload (F5) takes a long time on non-cached pages

Tags: drupal, varnish

Situation:
Varnish 2.1.4 lenny (latest stable) is running succesfully on Debian/Apache with mod_php.

I've got multiple Drupal sites running on this server and some are Varnish enhanced (e.g. using Pressflow). These sites work as expected.

The other sites, who aren't using the reverse-proxy, load fine when you enter the address or click around but take a really weird long time (30-45 secs) to load when you refresh the page using F5 or Ctrl+F5.

I don't think it's a VCL configuration thing; if I do a return (pass) immeditaley for one of these domains, the problem persists. Could this be related to [this issue](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/varnish/misc/16808)?

Answer (score 1):

Are the sites that arn't using varnish still going through it?

For debugging, I would have a look at the net tab with firebug, it should give you an indication of what is taking its' time. It could be that the itial page load is fine but the other resources are taking a long time to get through.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out varnish 2.1.4 has some kind of problem with Apache's Keep-Alive functionalitiy (which was On). Turning it Off solved both problems!